# General overview about Recursion (free online texts)

Tags: reference-request, recurrence-relations, recursion

I'm looking for free online texts about recursion.

What I'm looking for formal definitions* of "all" (most of) the different types of recursion and from different points of views like Category theory too .

*For example I did read a text where the author talks about the "successor algebra"  $(\Bbb N,S)$ (he calls it in this way) and how there exist an unique homomorphism $f: \Bbb N \rightarrow X$ between the "successor algebra" and another structure $(X,e)$ such that $f \circ S = e \circ f$ and that $f$ can be easily identified with a function defined recursively on the natural numbers by $S$ and $e$*

so what I need is:

> *A general overview of everything that concerns the recursion in a synthetic way but **NOT FROM THE POINT OF VIEW OF COMPUTER.***

---

> note: I'm also interested if there is some general discussion of the
>   process of recursion as a kind function $R$ that map functions, for
>   example $f$ and $S$ to another function $F=R(f,S)$  that is "defined
>   recursively"

---

Related Question: [Differend kind of recursion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752079/differend-kind-of-recursion)

Comment: It seems to me your wish to have a "formal definition" and to treat "all the different types of recursion and from different points of views" are antithetic.  A formal definition in mathematics will be based on an agreed foundation.  The foundation may be narrow as in elementary number theory, or broad as in a set theoretic treatment.  A sweeping treatment might take in the similarities and limitations of different points of view, but at the expense of formality.

Comment: you are right, in fact I dont look for ONE formal definition of ALL the DIFFERENT kind of recursion [bla bla...] I think is better to say "FORMAL DEFINITIONS*". @hardmath

Comment: Recursion is one of the most fundamental concepts in mathematics, so any comprehensive treatment will be a complete library.